# a double value got assigned by a subtraction got weird value

Tags: c#, double

// why does this code gives this value?
// shouldn't that the value be 0.9D ?

double test = 360.9D;

test -= 360D;

// test = 0.89999999999997726

Comment: Now try with `var test = 360.9M;` and `test -= 360M;`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to inherent floating point imprecision that occurs when you want to store fractional base-10 numbers in binary. [Wikipedia provides a good explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)

Basically you can't store all fractional base-10 numbers exactly in binary. The fractional portion is made up of sums of 2^n where n is a negative integer.

So to approximate 0.9, it will be 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 0/16 + 0/32 + 1/64 + ... and so on until the sum approximates 0.9, but you can see that the series will never exactly equal 0.9.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Pete were these comments meant for me or the question author? If they were meant for me, can you explain how I can enhance my answer?

Comment: The binary expansion of 0.9 decimal is 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 0/16 + 0/32 + 1/64 + ...   No 1/16 or 1/32 in it.

Comment: Also, you can simplify "reciprocals of 2^n where n is a positive integer" to either "2^-n where n is a positive integer" or "2^n where n is a negative integer"

Comment: @Luke they were meant for the author, and also everyone who comes across this page.  They enhance your answer by providing additional resources of which there are many available.

Comment: @Pete comments are generally to state requests to improve a post, if you have extra info/alternative answers provide one on your own (unless good answer already exists)... I.e. an example of proper comment would be "it is a bad idea to use word 'decimal' speaking about floating point numbers in C# because the `decimal` type in C#/.Net actually does support precise numbers and math with `decimal` would produce results expected by OP".

Comment: @Pete in that case these comments are probably better placed under the question rather than my answer

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Your example makes a fair criticism of the use of `decimal` in my answer. Replaced with base-10

Comment: @Luke yes that would have been more cromulent, however, I made a mistake, so here we are.